# Why did my wall-mounted garage door opener button stop working?

Tags: garage-door-opener

Yesterday, my wall-mounted garage door opener was working fine. Today, the opener is not working. There is no green light or any other sign of it working. I tried pressing it a few times but no response.

The opener still works with the remote outside the garage to enter.

I opened the button and touched both wires together as mentioned in another post but that didn't open the garage door.

Comment: What's the make and model of the opener and button?

Comment: Mousie chewed the wire...or something similar.

Comment: Is it a hardwire controller? If so it doesn't need batteries.  However just recently I've started noticing in garage buttons that are also really wireless and just screwed to the wall, in that case there might be batteries to replace.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by opening up the opener, and making sure the wires for the switch are securely connected.

Inspecting the cable for damage, would be the next step. This would include testing the wires for continuity, to make sure there's not damage that couldn't be seen.

Check the control board in the opener for any fuses, and make sure any fuses are good.

Answer (score 0):

Then identify the connections on your opener motor unit that go to the switch.  Short them directly to see if the door activates.

Of course you look first to see if its mains voltage or Ultra low voltage like 12V and take appropriate precautions.

If this works, your wiring is damaged and will need to be checked.  If this doesn't work, the circuit in the motor housing is unhappy and needs a closer look.

You can also check the switch+wall/ceiling wiring by connecting a battery and lightbulb to the bare ends, then have an assistant press the wall button.  Your light should light up.

Comment: Most garage door buttons dont work like that now. Shorting them may even damage the opener.